# How to download parts of the same file from different sources with curl/wget?

Tags: macos, download, wget, curl

I have a quite large file hosted on five different servers.

I would like to be able to download different parts of the file from each server and subsequently concatenate the parts, in order to produce the original file.

Is there any way to do this with curl/wget or any other OS X command-line tools?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It seems (potentially) relevant to others and is very specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**aria2** is the solution for multiple downloads of same file from different locations

http://aria2.sourceforge.net/

in your case : `aria2c -s5 host1/bigfile host2/bigfile ... host5/bigfile`

better late than never...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!