# How do I download a single file in 2 parts to different locations using wget?

Tags: linux, download, wget

Hi I need to use wget (or curl or aget etc) to download a file to two different download destinations by downloading it in two halves:

```
First: 0 to 490000 bytes of file
Second: 490001 to 1000000 bytes of file.
```

I will be downloading this to separate download destinations and will merge them back to speed up the download. The file is really large and my ISP is really slow, so I need to get help from friends to download this in parts (actually in multiple parts)

The question below is similar but not the same as my need:
[How to download parts of the same file from different sources with curl/wget?](https://superuser.com/questions/115734/how-to-download-parts-of-same-file-from-different-sources-with-curl-wget)

**aget**

aget seems to download in parts but I have no way of controlling precisely which part (either in percentage or in bytes) that I wish to download.

**Extra Info**

Just to be clear I do not wish to download from multiple locations, I want to download *to* multiple locations. I also do not want to download multiple files (it is just a single file). I want to download parts of the same file, and I want to specify the parts that I need to download.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With curl you should be able to do

```
curl -o customname -r0-499 <url>
```

where 0 - 500 would be the byte range

[curl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) look at the -r option

Posted by ewindisch in comment

> It is better not to use -O here as the OP would like to specify the destinations. curl -o file.part1 -r0-490000 $url & curl -o file.part2 -r490001- $url – ewindisch

Comment: It is better not to use -O here as the OP would like to specify the destinations. curl -o file.part1 -r0-490000 $url & curl -o file.part2 -r490001- $url